# Fiege Fiat Shamir Question about quadratic residues

Tags: math, cryptography, modulo

I am currently studying Fiege-Fiat Shamir and am stuck on quadratic residues. I understand the concept i think but im not sure how to calculate them for example how would i calculate

```
v   |  x^2 = v mod 21  |   x =?
___________________________________
1     x^2 = 1 mod 21    1, 8, 13, 20
4     x^2 = 4 mod 21    2, 5, 16
7     x^2 = 7 mod 21    7, 14
9     x^2 = 9 mod 21    3, 18
15    x^2 = 15 mod 21   6, 15
16    x^2 = 16 mod 21   4, 10, 11, 17
18    x^2 = 18 mod 21   9, 12
```

I do not understand how the column x=? is calculated. Can anyone help me maybe explain the method?

Comment: 19 = -2 is missing in the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand column shows the positive integers less than `21` (the modulus) that have quadratic residue equal to the values in the left-hand column. So, for example, the integers `1, 8, 13` and `20` all have quadratic residue equal to `1` modulo `21`. This means that their squares are congruent to `1` modulo `21`. For example,

```
8 * 8 = 64 = 63 + 1 = 21 * 3 + 1 =. 0 + 1 mod 21 =. 1 mod 21
```

where I am using `=.` to represent congruency modulo `21`. Similarly,

```
13 * 13 = 169 = 168 + 1 = 21 * 8 + 1 =. 0 + 1 mod 21 =. 1 mod 21
```

and

```
20 * 20 = 400 = 399 + 1 = 21 * 19 + 1 =. 0 + 1 mod 21 =. 1 mod 21.
```

Finding these numbers is called finding square roots mod `n`. You can find them using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (assuming that you can factor the modulus).